# How to `cp` multiple files from S3 to local machine in one command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cp

I am using `aws-vault` and am interested in `cp`ing multiple files from S3 to my local machine. The filenames do not follow any particular pattern. I was hoping for a command of the form

```
aws-vault exec <ROLE> aws s3 cp s3://path_to_file1 ~/file1 | aws s3 cp s3://path_to_file2 ~/file2
```

but a pipe like this doesn't work. The main reason I want to get this in one command is so that I only have to authenticate once, instead of for every single `aws-vault` call.

Comment: Everything is possible with one command but why? Write a script,... Can you share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Without aws-vault, in your case, you won't be authenticated so that won't work.

Try this command, it should not ask every single time.

```
aws-vault exec <ROLE> aws s3 cp s3://path_to_file1 ~/file1 | aws-vault exec <ROLE> aws s3 cp s3://path_to_file2 ~/file2
```